# Returning string in place of None without if statement

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to achieve the same outcome as the code below without making a temp variable and not using a if statement? I have tried multiple things but I am quite new to python.

```
 def get_value(dictionary, key):
    temp = dictionary.get(key)
    if temp = None:
        return "Sorry this item doesn't exist"
    else:
        return temp
```

i.e. of what I am trying to achieve

```
 def get_value(dictionary, key):
     return dictionary.get(key) else return "Sorry this item doesn't exist"
```

Comment: `return dictionary.get(key, "Sorry this item doesn't exist")`?

Comment: `if temp is None` is preferred to `if temp == None` (assuming `=` is just a typo for `==`).

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea in the first place... Suppose you call `get_value({"a": "Sorry this item doesn't exist"}, "a")`. The return value will be `"Sorry this item doesn't exist"`. But how do you know whether it returned the actual value belonging to the dict, or your failsafe message?

Comment: Another pattern you'll see is something like `return dictionary.get(key) or "Sorry this item doesn't exist"` as a kind of poor mans null coalescing operator.  Be careful of this though, because all falsy values, like `[]`, `0`, or `False` will then return your default string.

Comment: @Kevin That is a good point I never thought about that, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify a default value when calling `get()` on a dictionary. Try this:

```
def get_value(dictionary, key):
    default = "Sorry this item doesn't exist"
    return dictionary.get(key, default)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank-you

Answer (score 1):

Returning a string instead of `None` is something of an anti-pattern, since there's no way to distinguish between `"Sorry this item doesn't exist"` as an error message or as the actual value associated with the given key. Raise an exception instead.

```
def get_value(dictionary, key):
    try:
        return dictionary[key]
    except KeyError:
        raise Exception("Sorry, this item doesn't exist")
```

You can define your own custom exception in place of `Exception`. Also consider whether your exception really adds anything of value over the `KeyError` already raised by `dict.__getitem__`.

Comment: `else` -> `except`?